# namedtuple with a factory-style constructor

Tags: python

I have a namedtuple that can serve two different purposes:

```py
IODataTuple = namedtuple('IODataTuple', ['network_io', 'disk_io'])
```

I want to create two different factory methods for the different kinds of tuples. Is it good practice to have them within a class like so?

```py
class IOData(object):
  @staticmethod
  def network_data(network_io):
    return IODataTuple(network_io, None)
  @staticmethod
  def disk_data(disk_io):
    return IODataTuple(None, disk_io)
```

Or is this pattern *non-pythonic*? Maybe just keep the two separate methods, without them being in a class?

Comment: Maybe the example is too simple. From what I can see that seems like a totally unnecessary layer of indirection (not only the class but also the `namedtuple` - mostly because it sets one element to None).

Comment: If your class consists of only two static methods, then yeah, just make these module-level functions.